# Does $\exp{(f_n)}$ converge to $\exp{(f)}$ uniformly if $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, uniform-convergence

There is a similar question [The function sequence $(\exp(f_n))$ converges uniformly if the function sequence $(f_n)$ converges uniformly.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326359/the-function-sequence-expf-n-converges-uniformly-if-the-function-sequence) which states that if the real part of $f$ is bounded, it holds.

I was wondering if we can drop the condition that the real part of $f$ is bounded. My intuition says no, but did not come up with any reasonable counterexample or proof.

Any hints or ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $f(z)=z$ and $f_n(z)=z-\frac1n$.

Comment: Ah, I should have gone for the simplest example... I feel like an idiot. Thank you.